# declarativenetrequest not working with manifest v3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I want to redirect the website using chrome Extension manifest version v3.
I went though multiple articles but not getting a working solution.

For simplicity let us say if someone opens google.com I want to redirect to bing.com. I tried below code , but it's not working.

Can someone help me with the fix.

empty_rules.json

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "priority": 1,
  "action": {
    "type": "redirect",
    "redirect": {
      "url" : "http://www.yahoo.com"
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "urlFilter": "google.com",
    "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
  }
}]
```

manifest.json

```
background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
"permissions": ["nativeMessaging", "declarativeNetRequest","declarativeNetRequestFeedback"],
"host_permissions": [
    "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
"manifest_version": 3,
"declarative_net_request" : {
    "rule_resources" : [{
      "id": "ruleset_1",
      "enabled": true,
      "path": "empty_rules.json"
  }]
}
```

Wrote the code the check the rules been executed in background.js as

```
chrome.declarativeNetRequest.onRuleMatchedDebug.addListener(
    (e) => console.log("onRuleMatchedDebug" + JSON.stringify(e))
);
```

and got the output as below :

```
{"request": {"documentLifecycle":"active","frameId":0,"frameType":"outermost_frame","method":"GET","parentFrameId":-1,"requestId":"642","tabId":78917798,"type":"main_frame","url":"https://www.google.com/"},"rule":{"ruleId":2,"rulesetId":"_dynamic"}}
```

Wondering how come the matching rule id is coming as
"rule":{"ruleId":2,"rulesetId":"_dynamic"}} , ideally it should match "ruleid","1"

Comment: The code works correctly here, it redirects and prints as expected. You can test it in a new browser profile. I guess you've called updateDynamicRules at some point. You can remove the rules by calling getDynamicRules and then updateDynamicRules. You can also simply remove and install extension again.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, I was only updating the extension with refresh button, uninstalling and reinstalling the extension solved the issue.